# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x1010864a0>

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow to read encode and decode image ,but while doing this getting above error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import base64
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import io
############################################ IMAGE READ #################################################
#tensorflow==2.10.0

image = tf.io.read_file('Cotton American boll worm 2.jpg' , name = None)
############################################ IMAGE DECODING #################################################
b_64 = tf.io.encode_base64(image, pad=False, name=None)
decode_image = tf.io.decode_base64(b_64, name=None)
sol = io.BytesIO(decode_image)
image = Image.open(sol)#HERE IS THE ERROR
```

Comment: Please `print(decode_image[:20])` and add results by clicking [edit].

Comment: {{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/

Comment: getting this error after adding the line

Comment: Mmm.. `print(type(decode_image))`

Comment: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 1):

After using `print()` to check what it has in variables I found it converts full object `tensor` to `bytes` in `BytesIO` (it serializes tensor) but it has to get only raw `bytes` from `tensor`.

And I found it needs `.numpy()` to get expected data from `tensor`.

```
sol = io.BytesIO(decode_image.numpy())
```

---

Full working code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import base64
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import io

image = tf.io.read_file('image.jpg', name=None)

b_64 = tf.io.encode_base64(image, pad=False, name=None)
#print('b_64:', b_64)

decode_image = tf.io.decode_base64(b_64, name=None)
#print('decode_image:', decode_image)          # tensor
#print('decode_image:', decode_image.numpy())  # bytes

#sol = io.BytesIO(decode_image)         # tensor
#print('sol:', sol.getvalue())          # wrong data

sol = io.BytesIO(decode_image.numpy())  # bytes
#print('sol:', sol.getvalue())          # correct data

image = Image.open(sol)
image.show()
```