# UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000218A687E040>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

***I am getting this error while training VGG model***
***there might be an issue with any/some of images, but how could I trace them?***
Code:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\\Users\\SUCHAL\\Desktop\\Research in Computing\\Thesis\\Untitled Folder\\New_Dataset\\train',
                                                 target_size = (224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\\Users\\SUCHAL\Desktop\\Research in Computing\\Thesis\\Untitled Folder\\New_Dataset\\test',
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

# fit the model
r = model.fit_generator(training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=30, steps_per_epoch=len(training_set), validation_steps=len(test_set))
```

Error:

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000218A687E040>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a bit more detail, particularly what you've set each variable to.  What is ```training_set```?  etc..

Comment: today was question with similar error - maybe you have similar problem: [PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <\_io.BytesIO object at 0x1010864a0>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143780/pil-unidentifiedimageerror-cannot-identify-image-file-io-bytesio-object-at-0x/74144923#74144923)

Comment: you could always use `for`-loop and train it on single images - and this way you could get which image makes problem.

Comment: @furas it looks like a different issue. I got one similar issue but was not able to execute that code. Getting error in that as well. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232295/discussion-between-lescurel-and-everydaydeveloper

Comment: @furas, there are 17000 images. so how could I use a single image every time to trace that image?

Comment: @ewokx, [train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255...] [test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)...] [ training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\\Users\.....] [test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\\Users\ .......]   not able to edit main question so mentioned here

Comment: how about `for`-loop ? Or you could test on half images to see if it is in first part on in second part, and next split it again, etc. OR maybe all your images are wrong and it will stop on first image

Comment: @furas could you please help me with the code?

Comment: @furas I tried with 50-60 images. They were working fine

Comment: how to help you with code if you show only one line of code. And I don't have access to your data to test it.

Comment: @ewokx I have added my program part.

Comment: My guess is that you have a binary file in your training set directory that isn't an image.  Other than that..   no clue.

Comment: @ewokx, thank you for your valuable time. yes, it was one corrupted image, but it was a large dataset. I've changed my complete dataset now.